# Django i18n work in code but not in templates?

Tags: django, internationalization, django-templates, translation

I created my language files (which contain the messages from my templates) and then compiled them.

here is what I have in my settings file:

```
USE_I18N = True
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    '/srv/www/rewards_system/locale',
)

ugettext = lambda s: s
LANGUAGES = (
    ('bg', ugettext('Bulgarian')),
    ('en', ugettext('English')),  
)
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'bg'
USE_L10N = True
```

And what I have as a result is that all the translations run from the code with `ugettext()` function translate perfectly to Bulgarian but all from inside templates `({% trans "word" %})` appear in English.

I have `{% load i18n %}` on top of my template.

I am loading it with [render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) function

```
render(request,
       'company/signup.html', 
       { 'form': form })
```

which means that RequestContext is sent to the template.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Do you see your translations in the po-file?

Comment: Yes, the messages from the template(and respectively translations) appear in the .po file.

Comment: can you try to print the current language to make sure it is acctually not just running english.

Comment: It actually prints english but the translation from code are in bulgarian ?

Comment: Django will read which is the current language from a few parameters and then render the text for that language. An idea is to hardcode activate('bg') just before you call render.

Comment: Yes this actually translated the template message. But these two continue to stay strangely separated. When I try to switch languages using the /i18n/setlang/ it changes only the language in the Templates but not in code.

Comment: I fixed it now. The problem with /i18n/setlang/ translating only templates was because I was using ugettext instead of ugettext_lazy in my form. Thanks for helping me to find the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and eventually solved it using `strace`. My problem was caused by incorrect names of the language sub-directories inside `locale` directory. It's a bit misleading because the language codes as passed by browsers or configured in `settings.py` contain hyphen (e.g. `zh-CN`) while the directory names need to contain underscore (e.g. `locale/zh_CNL`). And this is actually Django is searching for:

```
stat("/myapp/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo", 0x7fff08a385c0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Once the directory has been renamed into `ru_RU` Django was able to find it:

```
stat("/home/webcookies/wps2/locale/ru_RU/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=689, ...}) = 0
```

I also found the following code snipppet useful in testing translation correctness:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")

from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from django.utils.translation import activate
activate('ru-RU')
print(_("English text to be translated"))
```

Comment: The comment relating to hyphens in the language code was an absolute 'god send'. For various reasons I need to work with language codes that contain hyphens. This was breaking Django localization and I couldn't figure out why. Renaming the language folders, substituting underscore for hyphen made everything work at my end. Thanks v. much :)